Async operation like fetch, async/await are executed after syncronous code is executed then why microtask queue is given more priority?
micro task Queue consist of callbacks/resolved functions from fetch, async/await. but why its given more priority then callback queue because sync code is executed first and then afterward async function is executed then why/how microtask queue is given more priority then callback queue ?
I read more about the concept but still confused on it.

Why shouldn't it be higher priority? These decisions were made by the language committee and there's nothing you can do about it. It works the way it works.

What do you mean by "callback queue"? Is that something specific to qjsengine?

I'll ignore the qjsengine as I believe this was a typo and will instead answer about the WHATWG's HTML event-loop concepts.
MICROTASKS ARE NOT BEING GIVEN MORE PRIORITY THAN OTHER TASKS
Too often I see this assertion and it becomes more and more confusing, moreover since now we can tap into the task prioritization system. microtasks just don't participate at all in this task prioritization system.
Microtasks were introduced in the event-loop design as a way to handle a batch of possibly contradicting modifications made on objects during a script 1 execution. For instance the oldest API we still have that does use this system is the MutationObserver API. Instead of having a lot of JS callbacks fire during another script's execution, leading to poor performances and possibly hard to debug issues, it collects all the mutations that happened during the script execution, and once the script is over2, it will trigger its notification callback. It could have queued a common task, like setTimeout() does, but then that would mean that if the script was executed during the update-the-rendering steps of the event-loop (e.g. inside a requestAnimationFrame() callback), you would see the changes on screen before being able to act on it. So the idea of a microtask, that would execute right after the script that spawned it came to life.
This design was not only useful for web APIs and when the ECMA group developed the Promise concept, they integrated it directly with the concept of microtask in HTML. So Promises would invoke their callbacks in microtasks too, allowing user-land scripts to perform the same kind of "trigger-at-the-end" operation.3
So, yes, there will be a microtask checkpoint when the script execution is done, before any other script can run, simply because that's what it's for: execute a callback when the script execution is done.
As I mentioned at the beginning, there is a prioritization system, at the task level4: at the start of an event-loop cycle, the engine will choose one task among all the ones queued in the various task sources. The priority is done by choosing one task source over another.
Even for things like fetch which does expose a Promise based API, the prioritization system can kick in: The returned Promise is going to be resolved in an actual task, which will do only that (related Q/A). So if a UI event occurs at the same time that the fetch operation is done, the browser can say "let's handle the UI event first". That's prioritizing.
Microtasks on the other hand are forced to run when the current script ends, there is no prioritization.


1. Basically whatever calls prepare to run a script, be it a callback, an actual <script>, or whatever executes JS
2. It's actually when all currently JS scripts are done running. So if you do synchronously invoke a callback through your script and that callback queues a microtask, the microtask will only execute when your script is done executing, not right after the callback.
3. async/await functions being mostly syntax sugar over Promises, they act exactly the same for that matter.
4. Tasks are yet another beast than callbacks, they're purely specs constructs to tell the browser to do stuff, and don't necessary invoke JS.

Aiming for a reversal badge? :D

@Bergi Ouch, I never play the rep/badge game and was only aiming at making things clearer. But it's true the question isn't great, though it somehow contains a lot of the misconceptions a lot of us have on this subject so it was a quite solid ground for this answer.

FYI using the microtask queue to run Promise reaction jobs was not instigated by the ECMA group who ended up rejecing a proposal to do so as an implementation issue. Subsequently to this using the microtask queue for promise jobs appeared in  HTML standards. This  answer to a related question about the motivation to introduce a separate microtask queue (with an emphasis on promise work) goes into more detail.

@traktor yes, ES Promises don't use the microtask concept as is because ES can be ran in environments where there is no event-loop (e.g. in Worklets), and still it needs to work™.  However I'm pretty sure that when they (IIRC Domenic Denicola, HTML editor) championed it, it was pretty clear that in HTML this would end up in the already existing microtask queue, and thus they needed to provide the PromiseJobReactionINeverRememberTheActualName hook so that HTML can use it. That's what I meant by my maybe unclear "integrated with the concept of...".

FWIW I dug up some old discussions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68525922/ about when the microtask queue got designed in HTML.

Microtask queue more priority because faster.
Sync code run first, then microtask, then callback. Microtask like async/await finish quick. Callback queue slower, used for setTimeout, setInterval.
Microtask make app smooth, no delay. Callback can wait longer. This make app better and faster.

This is as good an answer as any. It's not necessarily exhaustively accurate, but worrying about how task dispatch works is, to me, a waste of time for 99% of normal software development in JavaScript.

"Microtask like async/await finish quick. Callback queue slower" - no. There's no reason to assume that microtasks are quicker to execute than other tasks. Or that they "can wait" less. And what does any of this have to do with the smoothness of the app?
